# Other divs overlap behind if I use percentages

Tags: html, css, web

I am experiencing a problem in CSS where my other divs overlap to the image above if I use percentages, for px I have no problem and the divs stay in place. I want the image to be in full-width size though as like a hero image and want it responsive in all screen sizes.

[Screenshot of site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMy2S.png)

```css
.img-slider{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 90px;
  background: #18191C;
}

.img-slider .slide{
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  clip-path: circle(0% at 0 50%);
}

.img-slider .slide.active{
  clip-path: circle(150% at 0 50%);
  transition: 1.3s;
  transition-property: clip-path;
}

.img-slider .slide img{
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-slider">
  <div class="slide active">
    <img src="images/Thumb/img1.png" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Native Fixtures</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="images/Thumb/img2.png" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Slide 02</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="3.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Slide 03</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="4.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Slide 04</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="5.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Slide 05</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use flex box with the justify-content:space-around setting and flex-grow you can create the effect your looking for.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/